# Find events associated with users on a certain date in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, datetime, node.js, ecmascript-6, mongodb

I have this script which works perfectly but I experienced some delays because of these 2 `for` loops `[i][j]`. Is there any way to do the same function but with a better and more effective process like `foreach` or other?

```
User.find({}).lean(true).exec((err, users) => {
        let getTEvent = [];
        //nested loops() //callbacks
   
        for (let i =0 ; i < users.length; i++) { 
          if(users[i].events && users[i].events.length) {
const dt = datetime.create();
dt.offsetInDays(0);
const formatted = dt.format('d/m/Y');
// console.log(formatted)
for (let j = 0; j < users[i].events.length; j++) {
    if(users[i].events[j].eventDate === formatted) {
      getTEvent.push({events: users[i].events[j]});
      }  
    }
  }
}


   return res.json(getTEvent)
    });
```

The main role of this code is:

1. find the data in Mongodb: find all users with or without events
2. loop through data and select events made by any users
3. push the results in an array which is `getEvent`in order to be useful later for the client side

Details:

The `User` is the model: `const User = require('../models/users.model');`
and `events` is `[]` array.

This is Mongodb structure of that models:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :D okey noted!

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I tried to explain the main role of my script :-D

Comment: `I got some delays` in *coding* or in execution of the code? Measurement results & method?

Comment: @greybeard, Delays in execution of the code what I'm looking is if there something more efficient than this?

Comment: What is `User`? Obviously it is a service/model class that has a `find` method... can that find method accept parameters like filters for events? Please [edit] your post to include as much detail as possible - this will help reviewers give better reviews

Comment: Yea, we're missing context here.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ  I updated my question hope I clarified everything

Comment: @Mast , I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main cause of your delays is not a nested `for` but rather the fact that you extract all data from your MongoDB collection into memory. What you can do is:

1. calculate formatted date once
2. query just those users that contain given event date instead of populating all users in memory. Here's the [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

This will look roughly like the following:

```
const dt = datetime.create();
dt.offsetInDays(0);
const formatted = dt.format('d/m/Y');

User.find({
        "events": {
            eventDate: formatted
        }       
    }).lean(true).exec((err, users) => {
        let getTEvent = [];
        //nested loops() //callbacks

        for (let i = 0 ; i < users.length; i++) { 
          if(users[i].events && users[i].events.length) {           
            for (let j = 0; j < users[i].events.length; j++) {
                if(users[i].events[j].eventDate === formatted) {
                  getTEvent.push({events: users[i].events[j]});
                }  
            }
          }
        }


   return res.json(getTEvent)
});
```

Comment: I think you are right I see, instead of populating all data user just fetch the data needed with only one connexion DB, so as per your answer my code is corrected the nested loops part?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your comment correctly. My point is that you fetch from mongo only users that contain events in question. And that will reduce memory footprint

Comment: ok thank you so much, I asked something else of the code that I wrote is efficient no need for another modification ?

Comment: I think that is the only modification that is needed. You can't eliminate nested loop completely, since you need to filter out only needed events.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve with this code, and you haven't really described it very well. I'm reasonably sure, though, that all this code should be completely eliminated in favour of a MongoDB query, so that the processing is done by the database without shipping the full dataset to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I was planning to suggest filtering the users in the query, as Bohdan suggested. Below are more suggestions.

#### Variable declarations

Another suggestion is to default to using `const` for all variables including arrays. This helps avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085). If you determine that you need to re-assign a variable then switch it to `let`.

The variable `getTEvent` can be declared with `const` since it is never re-assigned. If you had to remove all elements the `length` property could be set to `0`.

#### looping apporach

Also you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops instead of `for` loops when the index is not used for anything other than selecting a current index. You could also consider a functional approach with [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - this would avoid the need to push filtered items manually.